# me sale este error. UnexpectedValueException Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\AspiranteController]

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::get('aspirante','AspiranteController');



<?php
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

  class AspiranteController extends Controller
  {
    public function index()
    {
      return view('aspirante.index');
    }

    public function create()
    {
      return view('aspirante.create');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu ruta no está llamando a un controlador de tipo **Resource** por lo tanto debes especificar a qué método deseas llamar en tu ruta, de este modo

```
Route::get('aspirante','AspiranteController@index’);
```

De este modo la ruta sabe que en `/aspirante` debe acceder a la lógica del método `index` y así por cada uno

Comment: !!!  mira que al querer editar un registro utilizo esta ruta!! Route::get('aspedit/{id}', 'AspiranteController@edit');  pero no se porque cuando ya el navegador se dirige a ella no me toma el layout, osea solo me muestra la plantilla con su form pero no toma los estilos del layout. puedes ayudarme con eso.. Por favor me urge.....

Comment: No se si sea por la ubicación de la carpeta de los estilos css y los archivos js. Pero la verdad no le he hallado el problema del porque será!!